# Making array const produces "use of null is not valid in this context" error

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I have a class like:

```
class SomeTests {
  private Guid[] someGuids = new Guid[] { ... }

  public void ThoseGuidsShouldAlwaysBeThere() {
    foreach (Guid g in someGuids) { // error appears here
        // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Semantically, I want `someGuids` to be `const`, since they shouldn't be updated, ever, except before recompiling the code. But adding the `const` keyword generates [error CS0168](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19w6t732%28v=vs.71%29.aspx): `null is not valid in this context.`

Reading the MSDN page for that error, it seems to me that the compiler thinks I'm doing this:

`foreach (Guid g in null) {`

I don't understand how adding `const` causes this problem here, and how to solve my semantic problem (list is read-only, not writable) -- keeping it as an array instead of a List is "almost" good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to make `Guid[]` a constant should give you an error of "A const field of a reference type other than string can only be initialized with null."

Make it `readonly` instead:

```
private readonly Guid[] someGuids = new Guid[] { Guid.NewGuid() };
```

When it's `readonly` you can also assign the value in the constructor:

```
public SomeTests()
{
    someGuids = new[] { Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid() };
}
```

As Jeffery mentioned in the comments, this solution prevents `someGuids` from being reassigned, but the items can still be modified. Jeffery addresses this issue in his answer.

Comment: I actually don't get the const-field-reference-type-nullz" error. Maybe it's a VS2008 bug; I can compile if I comment out my `foreach` iteration. Making it `readonly` and assigning the value out of the constructor works too.

Comment: This will not keep the collection from being modified, this will only keep it from being re-instantiated.  You can still modify the members. E.g.  `someGuids[0] = new Guid();`

Comment: @JefferyKhan that's right. Hardly warrants a downvote though. Question really has two parts to it.

Comment: Agreed, I'll remove it, however I would mention that piece.  The OP stated they do not wish the guids to be able to be changed: `since they shouldn't be updated, ever, except before recompiling the code`

Comment: And unfortunately, I can't remove my downvote unless you edit your q.

Answer (score 3):

The `readonly` keyword in this use is a bit misleading.  Look at it as preventing the collection from being re-instantiated rather than modified.

Example:

```
 private readonly Guid[] someGuids = new Guid[] { Guid.NewGuid() };

 //This will not compile because it is read-only.
 someGuids = new Guid[] { Guid.NewGuid() };

 //This still compiles, and the first member will be changed
 someGuids[0] = Guid.NewGuid();
```

I recommend you look into using `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<T>` in combination with the `readonly` keyword instead.

Example:

```
    public readonly ReadOnlyCollection<Guid> someGuids = new
       ReadOnlyCollection<Guid>(new Guid[] { Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid() });
```

The collection will no longer be able to be re-instantiated nor will its members be able to be modified.

Comment: This is NOT a compiler bug.  It behaves exactly as it is supposed to act.  If your goal is to prevent the guids from being changed once they're set, this is an option.  The other falls short.